# How do I set up paging in a c# .NET gridview based on row data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, pagination

My data look like this:

```
col1
------
val1
val1
val1
val2
val2
val3
```

I would like my GridView to page the data based on the value in col1.  So page 1 should show the 3 rows with `val1`.  Page 2 would show 2 rows with `val2`.  Page 3 would show 1 row with `val3`

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What type of datasource are you using?

Comment: A DataTable that is populated from MSSQL for now. I can change it if the right solution requires it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the "ORDER BY" in your mysql connection? It should look something like..

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable
  ORDER BY col1 ASC;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That will certainly sort the data, but not configure pagination in the way that I described.

Comment: It should actually. Show your datasource. I'm using and SqlDataSource and that populates my gridview. If you show your datasource, I'd be able to help more for sure.

Comment: I don't think you understand my question.  Sorting the data will not configure paging the way I want.  Paging is based on how many records you want to display per page.  I do not want to do that.  I want to show records based on their values.  So each page contains only rows that have the same value in `col1`

Comment: Ha, definitely misread that. My bad. I'll see if I can come up with a solution and I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the paging for Gridview and set the GridView page size to the actual limit u want.

Links that might help you:

1) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.allowpaging.aspx

2) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y71xk4a7.aspx